# ASP.net copy PDF from server to client sources

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, pdf, extjs

I am currently working on a system where I want to copy a PDF file from my server into the client's sources so that it can be opened in an `embed` tag.

So far I have the following server code...

```
[HttpGet("printpdf")]
public HttpResponse getPDF()
{
    System.Web.HttpResponse response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
    response.ClearContent();
    response.Clear();
    response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=preview.pdf;");
    response.TransmitFile("preview.pdf");
    response.Flush();
    response.End();
    return response;
}
```

and it gets called from the client with `extJS` as such...

```
Ext.define('RibbonMenu.view.dialogues.Print', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    mixins: {
        controlDisabler: 'RibbonMenu.view.ribbon.controls.ControlDisabler'
    },
    title: 'Print Preview',
    height: 800,
    width: 800,
    layout: 'fit',
    constrain: true,

    items: [{
        xtype: 'component',
        autoEl: {
            tag: 'embed',
            type: 'application/pdf',
            src: Ext.Ajax.request({
                    url: "/printpdf?",
                    method: "GET",
                    success: function (response, opts) {
                        console.log("Receieved PDF");
                        var pdf = response;
                        console.log(pdf)
                        return pdf
                    },
                    failure: function (response, opts) {
                        console.log("Failed to receive PDF")
                        console.log(response.status);
                    }
                })

        }}]

});
```

Now obvisouly this isn't right because the src attribute of my embed tag looks like

```
src="id:1;xhr:[object XMLHttpRequest];headers:[object Object];options:[object Object];async:true;binary:false;timeout:26;"
```

So, what I am hoping to do is find a way to actually copy this pdf from the server into the client's sources as opposed to just passing a pdf object.

**EDIT**

One thing to mention is that this functionality is meant to be used for a print preview by letting the user's browser handle the printing/viewing of the pdf. So with this is mind, this file copy to the user is meant to be a temporary copy that just exists within the session on the page, and only the user trying to print can see it.

**EDIT**

I want to copy the PDF into the sources. Somewhere into the file structure in the image below which would allow me to create a hard URL to point the embed tag at.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to host the pdf at some public place and populate the src attribute with the url for the file

```
<embed src="https://your.domain/pdf/your_pdf_file.pdf">
```

In your server side code you are embedding the file content into the response, but what you need to do is:

Copy the file into a public folder (I'm assuming the file is already in the filesystem but not in a publicly accesible place).

```
var sourcePath = "c://path/to/the/original/file.pdf";
var targetPath ="relative/url/to/public/folder/file.pdf";
FileSystem.CopyFile(sourcePath,  Server.MapPath(targetPath));
```

And return the url to the file in the response.

```
System.Web.HttpResponse response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
response.ClearContent();
response.Clear();
response.ContentType = "text/plain";
response.Write(targetPath);
response.Flush();
response.End();
return response;
```

Comment: I understand that. That is what I am trying to achieve. See my edit

Comment: Would this make it is so that the PDF is only available to a single user? Whichever solution I come up with needs to be such that each user only sees PDFs that are related to them.

Comment: No, it would be available to anyone who knew the url. You should update your question with this new information